# Does altering the amplitude of an mp3 file, using sox, alter the signal?

Tags: audio, mp3, sox

I've just used sox to reduce the amplitude by 3dB on an mp3 file, because the
song was playing back too loudly.

I used

```
sox input-file.mp3 output-file.mp3 gain -3
```

Does this processing alter the signal content in output-file.mp3 in any way*, or
perhaps cause it to deteriorate slightly? (*Apart from changing the amplitude of
course.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `sox` uncompresses and re-compresses lossy formats while processing (see `man sox`), and iterated compression will cause slight detoriation of quality.

To change the gain in an mp3 file, it's not necessary to re-encode it, because the gain values are separate from the encoded data. You can use applications like `mp3gain` to change the gain values directly, without causing detoriation in audio quality.